# Windows 8 Enterprise Fail to boot after environment variable setting

Tags: windows-8, php, environment-variables

I have some problem with my PC after using windows 8 enterprise edition. I use my PC for web development work.

So for using PHP framework i need to set the environment variables, in my case i set to `D:\xampp\htdocs\cake\lib\cake\console;D:\xampp\php;`.

But even i delete this variable before i shutdown my PC it still make my PC fail to boot. Always have to restoring the system for successful boot.

Really appreciated all suggestion.

Comment: Which environment variable did you set? PATH? Did you append the value that you mentioned, or did you just set the variable to that?

Comment: yes PATH. I have 3 partition C,D,F. My xampp i put in D:\ directory. I set variable to that via system setting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you modified the system variable named PATH to include only your additional paths on D:.  You should either

- Append your paths to the system variable. Do this by adding a semi-colon to the end of the current value and adding your paths.

**or**

- Create a user variable called PATH, and set its value to just your additional paths. Windows will add your additional paths to the system PATH value. (Windows 7 does this, at least. Hopefully 8 does also.) Note that you will have to do this for each Windows user, but if you are the sole user of your machine, that will not be an issue.

If I were to recommend one, it would be the second one.

[image]

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks for your reply. I try this but it still remain same. Restart my machine & keep fail to load. Maybe my windows is broken or something? which is better use 32 or 64 if your PC is needed to do coding and development?

Comment: A 64-bit machine can compile for 32-bit also.  I'm not sure if the reverse is true. I haven't seen a 32-bit machine in a while. ;)